# How to find maximum value of two numbers in python?

Tags: python, list

I want to get the maximum value from a list.

```
List = ['1.23','1.8.1.1']
print max(List)
```

If I print this I'm getting `1.8.1.1` instead of `1.23`.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: How is `1.8.1.1` a number? And why should it be/not be the answer?

Comment: What are you comparing? Version numbers?

Comment: yes they are verison numbers in MKS(version management tool)

Comment: will you accept a pseudo code solution since i don't know python?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is, to use tuple comparison.
Say:

```
versions = ['1.23','1.8.1.1']

def getVersionTuple(v):
    return tuple(map(int, v.strip().split('.')))
```

Now you can use, `print(max(map(getVersionTuple, versions)))` to get the maximum.

**EDIT**:

You can use `'.'.join(map(str, m))` to get the original string (given `m` holds the max tuple).

Comment: with this output is (1, 23).Instead it should give 1.23

Answer (score 0):

These aren't numbers, they are strings, and as such they are sorted lexicographically. Since the character 8 comes after 2, `1.8.1.1` is returned as the maximum.

One way to solve this is to write your own comparing function which takes each part of the string as an `int` and compares them numerically:

```
def version_compare(a, b):
    a_parts = a.split('.')
    b_parts = b.split('.')
    a_len = len(a_parts)
    b_len = len(b_parts)
    length = min(a_len, b_len)

    # Compare the parts one by one
    for i in range(length):
        a_int = int(a_parts[i])
        b_int = int(b_parts[i])

        # And return on the first nonequl part
        if a_int != b_int:
            return a_int - b_int

    # If we got here, the longest list is the "biggest"
    return a_len - b_len

print sorted(['1.23','1.8.1.1'], cmp=version_compare, reverse=True)[0]
```

Comment: Why do you need to sort? This function with slight updating can give max itself

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach - assuming these strings are version numbers - is to turn the version string to an integer list:

```
vsn_list=['1.23', '1.8.1.1']
print sorted( [ [int(v) for v in x.split(".")] for x in vsn_list ] )
```

When you compare strings, they are compared character by character so any string starting with '2' will sort before a string starting with '8' for example.